# php error syntax error, unexpected '$connect' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

hello when i open my web site i got this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$connect' (T_VARIABLE) 
>   /includes/connect_database on line 3

and this is my connect database

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/material_wallpaper/includes/variables.php'); 
var_dump($connect)
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this as java

Comment: @Akintunde Probably so we could easier use our duplicate hammers to close it as duplicate of one of questions from PHP tags.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon ; after `var_dump`

Comment: Vilsol it didn't work men

Comment: Akintunde   i just forgot my friend